# Python regex or | is greedy

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('.*&l=(.*)(&|$)')
>>> p.search('foo&l=something here&bleh').group(1)
'something here&bleh' # want to remove strings after &
>>> p.search('foo&l=something here').group(1)
'something here' # this is OK
```

The python documents (2.7) says that the or operator '|' is never greedy. But my codes has not been working fine. I want the regex to stop searching when it reached the next & instead going through the entire string.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex tries to match everything (`.*`), then when it reaches the end of the string, it begins to backtrack until it matches `&`. That's why you are getting that result.

Change your regex to

```
.*&l=(.*?)(&|$)
```

Adding the `?` will make your regex lazy.

---

Simple example that demonstrate the issue:

Let's say you want to match everything until the first `%` character appears, and let's say you write the following regex:

```
.*%
```

Let's see how the engine works given the string "abc%def%g".

It first see `.*`, will try to consume everything, so it'll match the whole string. But then, it tries to match `%` and fails, so it backtracks to the previous character, it's `g`, still no match. Will backtrack again, and then it reaches `%`, it *does* match! So you'll get `abc%def%` as a result.

Answer (score 3):

You need change `.*` inside the first capturing group to `[^&]*`

```
p = re.compile('.*&l=([^&]*)')
```

Your regex `p = re.compile('.*&l=(.*)(&|$)')` matches also the extra chars because `.*` inside the first capturing group is greedy which matches all the chars upto the last. You all know `$` matches the boundary which exists at the last. Hence finds a match.

So `.*` and then `$` finds a match, so it won't get backtarck.